# Initialise view variables for new record

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo

In my MVC, I populate forms with data from the model using an array. I am using PDO and fetch associative array this gives an array of fields that I can use to populate the view.

When the user requests a new record, the array is empty and unless I explicitly test the value of every variable before use, the script falls over with a non-existant index.

My approach previously was, for new records, to setup an empty array and pass this to the view. This is fine for simple forms, but when the view needs to use 10-15 variables this is a bit tedious.

What is the preferred method of doing this?
Should my view test every field before use, or should I create the empty array. If so, should the empty array be created in the controller or the model?

---

As an example, If the user wants to edit an existing record, the controller passes the ID number to the model and asks it for an array of current values for the record.

The controller passes this array to the view which then incorporates the values into a form for editing.

In contrast, when the controller receives a request for a *new* record, it knows there is no point in asking the model for the record because its new. It can't just call the view because the passed array does not contain the keys required by the form.

My current approach to this is to initialise an array of empty keys but this seems tedious, time wasting and prone to error as it needs to be maintained if the model changes.

eg:

```
$this->view->class['Code']=NULL;
$this->view->class['Description']=NULL;
$this->view->class['Image']=NULL;
$this->view->class['Judge']=NULL;
$this->view->class['Entries']=NULL;
$this->view->class['Absentees']=NULL;
```

etc

There has to be a better way?

Comment: The sad truth is, whatever you do and for whatever reason, you first of all need to fix it. So this is just an undefined index warning you're fighting with, and throwing PDO or MVC or View or Model onto this does not make this go away or anything different.

Comment: The current view instance should be requesting data from the model layer.

Comment: @hakre - I fix it by creating an associative array of empty keys within the controller - but I don't know if this is best practice.

Comment: If your template requires those keys, sure. Otherwise you get the errors.

Comment: @hakre I know exactly why I get errors - thats not the point of the posting.

Comment: Okay if you know why you get the errors, why can't you say what the preferred way to prevent these is? I mean, you know your very own code best, don't you?

Comment: Your current "point of posting" is *not constructive*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a band-aid for poor MVC design, but you could use a function like this,

```
function idx(&$array, $index = 0, $default = null) {
  return isset($array[$index]) ? $array[$index] : $default
}
```

In the view if you normal did `$class['Description']`

you would now use `idx($class, 'Description')`

---

You should not have to pass each attribute of your model individually. Instead, just pass the entire model object and access it from the view. Example:

`$this->view->entry = $myModelInstance;` where `$myModelInstance` is an instance of `Entry` or whatever class has the Code, Description, Image, Judges, etc attributes.

Then in the view, use something like `$entry->Description`

Comment: Thanks. Your response got me moving in the right direction. I should be thinking about the model having all the properties and less about using sql to prepare data for the view. I was stuck on thinking how I could simulate a response from the database when its a new record. Your words 'just pass the entire object model...' made me realise that the model was not just there to route db queries, but that I should be preparing an empty model and then populating it if there is a record match.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion setting propper defaults is a model issue.

Imagine a class like this:

```
class Car {

    protected $color;

    protected $vendor;


    public function __construct($color, $vendor) {
        $this->color = $color;
        $this->vendor = $vendor;
    }


    public static function getDefault() {
        return new Car('unknown', 'unknown');       
    } 

}
```

However. You told that you use arrays. You'll find a similar way for arrays. I would suggest to write a function like `getDefaultWhatever()` and place it in **model** part of  code.

Comment: please stop referring to [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) as "models".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll do this through the constructor. Something like event = new Event($id) If the event exists the constructor will load the properties from the DB otherwise if the $id is zero then the constructor will create empty properties  - or I could use a magic method to return empty response for un-initialised properties - not very failsafe though perhaps.